# Get current iCloud Sync Status

Tags: objective-c, synchronization, icloud, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

Does anybody know if there is a way to detect if the current `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` is up to date? For example, if I have turned on the Flight Mode or got no internet connection, iCloud is not able to Sync Data, but how can I tell the user that he is working with maybe old data?

I also tried to handle the `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification` but it doesn't get triggered by failure.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore but for iCloud + CoreData there's NO way to know if the data is synced or not. I assume for Key-Value storage it's the same.